# Custom Finder Methods error in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a Custom Finder Method in the model and trying to call it in the controller it is not found.

follows the code in the model VehiclesTable.php:

```
public function listarVeiculosDisponiveis(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->where(['empresa_id' => 1]);
}
```

in the file OrcamentosController.php I have the following method:

```
public function add()
{
    $orcamento = $this->Orcamentos->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $orcamento = $this->Orcamentos->patchEntity($orcamento, $this->request->data);
        $orcamento['empresa_id'] = $this->Auth->user('empresa_id');
        $orcamento['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

        if ($this->Orcamentos->save($orcamento)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('O orçamento foi salvo com sucesso.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Erro ao salvar orçamento, tente novamente.'));
        }
    }

    $clientes = $this->Orcamentos->Clientes->find('list', [ 'conditions' => ['empresa_id' => $this->Auth->user('empresa_id'), 'excluido' => 0], 'fields' => ['id', 'nome'] ]);

    $veiculos = TableRegistry::get('Veiculos');
    $veiculos_disponiveis = $veiculos->find('listarVeiculosDisponiveis');


    $users = $this->Orcamentos->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('orcamento', 'clientes', 'users', 'veiculos_disponiveis'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['orcamento']);
}
```

when running I get the following error: **Unknown finder method "listarVeiculosDisponiveis"**

Where can I be wrong? I did as you say in the documentation

Comment: Take a close look at [**the docs**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods) again, the fourth sentence should give it away.

Comment: @ndm
Thank you.
His answer was not the most accurate in the world, but made me reread the documentation and realize that the method should start with the word "find".
Thank you very much!